# Google App Engine Data Export to CSV TextProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, google-app-engine-python

So I have a textproperty variable in my Google App Engine (Python). I am exporting the data to csv through remote api.

```
import csv
class Tower_of_London_History(db.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    start_datetime = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    end_datetime = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True)
    duration_to_first_move = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    completed = db.BooleanProperty(required=True)
    tower_type = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    duration = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    total_violations = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    total_legal_moves = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    time_type = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    move_time_stamps = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    timezone = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    utc_to_local_delta = db.IntegerProperty(required=False)

def exportToCsvTower_of_London_History(query, csvFileName, delimiter):
    with open(csvFileName, 'wb') as csvFile:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writeHeaderTower_of_London_History(csvWriter)

        rowsPerQuery = 1000
        totalRowsSaved = 0
        cursor = None
        areMoreRows = True

        while areMoreRows:
            if cursor is not None:
                query.with_cursor(cursor)
            items = query.fetch(rowsPerQuery)
            cursor = query.cursor()

            currentRows =0
            for item in items:
                saveItemTower_of_London_History(csvWriter, item)
                currentRows += 1

            totalRowsSaved += currentRows
            areMoreRows = currentRows >= rowsPerQuery
            print 'Saved ' + str(totalRowsSaved) + ' rows'

        print 'Finished saving all rows.'

def writeHeaderTower_of_London_History(csvWriter):
    csvWriter.writerow(['email', 'start_datetime', 'end_datetime', 'duration_to_first_move (seconds)', 'completed',
                        'tower_type', 'duration (seconds)', 'total_violations', 'total_legal_moves', 'time_type',
                        'move_time_stamps', 'timezone', 'utc_to_local_delta (mins)']) #Output csv header

def saveItemTower_of_London_History(csvWriter, item):
    csvWriter.writerow([item.email, item.start_datetime, item.end_datetime, item.duration_to_first_move, 
                        item.completed, item.tower_type, item.duration, item.total_violations, item.total_legal_moves,
                        item.time_type, item.move_time_stamps, item.timezone, item.utc_to_local_delta]) # Save items in preferred format

query = Tower_of_London_History.gql("ORDER BY email")
exportToCsvTower_of_London_History(query, 'moment_exported_csv_files/tower_of_london_history.csv', ',')
```

I get the following error

```
BadValueError: Property move_time_stamps is 3085 bytes long; it must be 1500 or less.
```

For your information, I use the following to run the program : 
(On terminal) 
remote_api_shell.py -s APP ID
import file_name

I am wondering if there is any way TextProperty that is bigger than 1500 Bytes can be exported to Excel CSV.

Here's the full trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "export_moment_data.py", line 568, in <module>
    exportToCsvTower_of_London_History(query, 'moment_exported_csv_files/tower_of_london_history.csv', ',')
  File "export_moment_data.py", line 387, in exportToCsvTower_of_London_History
    items = query.fetch(rowsPerQuery)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2161, in fetch
    return list(self.run(limit=limit, offset=offset, **kwargs))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2330, in next
    return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1445, in from_entity
    return cls(None, _from_entity=entity, **entity_values)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 973, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 617, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2855, in validate
    % (self.name, len(value), self.MAX_LENGTH))
BadValueError: Property move_time_stamps is 3085 bytes long; it must be 1500 or less.
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the full traceback of your error message.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#TextProperty TextProperties can be longer than 1500, so it makes me think maybe you have old data where ```move_time_stamps``` used to be a ```StringProperty``` or there is something odd with your data.

Comment: @AaronD, I have added the full traceback

Comment: It only happens when there is a row with move_time_stamps that is over 1500 Bytes. I created a dummy row just to test it out. Otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: As stated here (according to your traceback): https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#2854 the exception is raised inside the `StringProperty` class, NOT the `TextProperty` one. Is there a chance you're querying a different class, NOT `Tower_of_London_History` where move_time_stamps is still a `StringProperty`? Or do you have the `Tower_of_London_History` class defined twice, with different types of properties?

Comment: @andy7586 May be locally you still have move_time_stamps defined as a StringProprty. When you run the remote api it uses your code from the local machine.